# Pass message to a background on select's .change() event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mustache

### The problem

I think I have confused myself with an overcomplicated chrome extension and can't figure out the solution.

Here's what an extension should do:

- It should check the URL and CSS of the page user is currently at via chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules and loads a content script
- Content script asks a background page for the initial data
- Background page sends the data back
- Content script send the data to an external mustache.js HTML template(which contains a single select tag in this example)
- Content script renders the template and injects it into a website
- **Every time select value gets changed content script sends a message to background asking for new data**

Every point works just fine except the **last one**.

So my question is: **How/where should I check for the select's .change() event**

---

### The code (simplified version)

*manifest.json*

```
{


    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "name": "Example extension", 
    "version": "4.20",  

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js", "jquery-2.1.1.min.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["*://www.example.com/*"],
        "js" : ["jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "content.js", "mustache.min.js"]
    }],

    "page_action":{

        "default_icon":{
            "19" : "images/icon19.png",
            "38" : "images/icon38.png"
        }
    },

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "to_be_injected.mustache.html"
    ],

    "permissions": [
        "http://www.example.com/*",
        "declarativeContent"
    ]


}
```

*to_be_rendered.mustache.html*

```
<script id="to_be_rendered">
    <select name="example-select" id="example-select">
        {{#options}}<option value='{{.}}'>{{.}}</option>{{/options}}
    </select>
</script>
```

*content.js*

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "init"}, function(response_data) {
  injectHtml(response_data);
});

function injectHtml(response_data){
    $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/to_be_rendered.mustache.html'),{})
        .done(function(template) {
            var rendered_template = Mustache.render($(template).filter('#to_be_rendered').html(), response_data);
            $("#container").append(rendered_template);
        });
}
```

Edit: grammar

Comment: Habe you already thought of `$("#container").append(rendered_template).find('select').on('change', function() { chrome.runtime.sendMessage( ... something using this.value ... ); });` ?